# Module not Found in angular 2 production mode?

Tags: angular, webpack

when I build production I am getting  the below error

> 39% building modules 244/473 modules 229 active
>   ...de_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.jsModuleNotFoundError: Module
>   not found

my angular 2 version

```
   "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/core": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/forms": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.6",
   "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.6"
```

I am using **web pack :2.1.0-beta.21**

Any one give the suggestion to solve this error ?

Comment: you have to include (import) toPromise in your code, just as the warning says.

Comment: when i run normally means without production i am not getting any error.why?

Comment: Have you used dynamic component load in DOM?

Comment: Yes.i used dynamic component

Comment: without webpack is it work?

Comment: no.it is not working and where should i write Promise in my code.means(in app.module.ts or any other file).i am getting when i did lazy loading to my project